# Is it possible to calculate the Kc for an irreversible reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium

Is it possible to calculate the Kc for an irreversible reaction? For instance, can we Calculate the $K_c$ for:

$$\ce{NaCl + AgNO3 -> NaNO3 + AgCl}$$

Comment: This question is a short, specific, conceptual query, and would also be a good dupe target for closing any future questions about it. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes.**

**ALL** reactions have an equilibrium constant. So do "irreversible" ones. However, The ratio of products and reactants can vary wildly.

$$
K_c=\frac{[\text{Products}]}{[\text{Reactants}]}
$$

For small values of $K$ ($<10^{-3}$):

There is a lot of reactant, while barely any product has formed. Hence, The reaction has barely proceeded and it is a **negligible** or **impossible** reaction.
$$\ce{Cu + FeSO4 -> No reaction}$$

For moderate values of $K$ ($>10^{-3}, <10^3$):

There is a roughly comparable amount of product in respect to the reactants. Hence, this is a **reversible reaction**.
$$\ce{NH3 ->N2 + 3H2}$$

For large values of $K$ ($>10^{3}$):

There is a lot of product, while barely any reactants are left. Hence, The reaction has nearly completed and it is an **irreversible** reaction.
$$\ce{NaOH + HCl -> NaCl + H2O}$$

As you can see, there is an equilibrium constant for your reaction.
It is just extremely large.